# ZKTeco - How to remove enrollment for specific date

Tags: c#, zkteco

I'm Using the [BioMetrix ZKTeko libraries](https://github.com/zaagan/BioMetrix/) for a development.

My company is using those terminals for the user enrollment, but we aren´t looking to delete whole the data at the same time after a syncronization. We want to keep it for few days. 
Exist a way to remove that information using `c#` and that library with a criteria like the `date` or the older 100 records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature available. You have to load all the users and validate the enrollment time and delete the user id which falls in your criteria to delete.

Comment: There is a feature, I'll post it.